# Error: invalid instruction suffix for `jmp` in x86

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I am learning x86 assembly language and I have been given a list of instructions for which I've to tell whether each of them is valid or not. While deassembling the instruction `jmpb *0x100` I am getting an error: *Error: invalid instruction suffix for 'jmp'* . Why is `jmpb *0x100` an invalid jump instruction in the x86?
On the other hand, `jmpw *0x100` works fine.

Comment: Because there is no byte size indirect jump. If you consult the instruction set reference you will see that you only have 16, 32 or 64 bit versions.

Comment: The operand-size for `jmp` determines whether it updates IP, EIP, or RIP.  Even a direct `jmp rel8` wouldn't be `jmpb`.